# How to display an rtf file in WPF with Powershell?

Tags: wpf, powershell, richtextbox

I've been googling in vain for hours, and can't seem to find a way to view an rtf file in a powershell WPF form.

I can get the rtf file using:

```
$myContent = gc c:\myContent.rtf
```

but when I try to display it using:

```
$RichTextBox.appendText($myContent)
```

I get the encoded rtf, not the properly formatted content.

Anyone have a way to do this? Loads of examples out there about how to do this in c#, but none for PowerShell.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.AppendText only works with strings, not raw RTF. RTF is a sequence of control codes mixed with raw text. You need to use a different method in order to parse it:

```
$stream = new-object IO.MemoryStream (`
       [Text.ASCIIEncoding]::Default.GetBytes($myContent))
$RichTextBox.Selection.Load($stream, [Windows.DataFormats]::Rtf)
```

Hope this helps,

-Oisin

Comment: Think I'm getting warmer, but get this error when I try to create the MemoryStream - New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "MemoryStream" and the argument count: "123".

Answer (score 2):

OK - so I finally got this to work with some tweaking of Oisin's post.

Will mark his as the "proper" answer, as I wouldn't have got here without him, but thought I'd post my code in case it helps anyone in future:

```
$myContent = gc "c:\myContent.rtf"
$ascii = (new-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).getbytes($myContent)
$stream = new-Object System.IO.MemoryStream($ascii,$false)
$RichTextBox.Selection.Load($stream, [Windows.DataFormats]::Rtf)
```

Cheers,

Ben

Comment: sorry,yeah, I probably broke it by trying to format it better to read. The backtick "`" is a line continuation character, like VB's underscore "_"